# Add an html attribute in a input field using an onchange method in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is the select button:

```
<select @change="selected" v-model="row.product_id" class="form-control" name="product_id" id="product_id">
    <option value="">Select Product</option>
    <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.id" v-text="item.product_name"></option>
</select>
```

And this is the onchange method:

```
selected(e){
    var id = this.row.product_id;
    axios.get('/estimate/product/' + id)
    .then((response)=>{
        this.product = response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }); 
}
```

In the onchange method I want to add an attribute `selected="selected"` to a option if it is selected. Is it possible? If so how can I do that?

Comment: the browser/HTML already does that visual selecting for you.

Comment: @Sergio Nope its not getting the attribute selected and when I am printing the page I am not getting the selected value. It prints "Select Product" not the selected value

Comment: can you please complete your example with the data object? so it will be easier to copy/paste your data to the code editor and maybe better understand what u are doing?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you're asking: when an option is selected, it automatically receives the selected prop. When printing the page, you will see the selected option being shown in the print preview. Otherwise, you can access the selected `<option>` based on the [`.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) attribute of the event target.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon when you use `v-model` you get that already. Can you explain better what you need?

Comment: Thanks @Terry for the hint. I have solved the print problem using some sort of JQuery (my print button is on a normal blade template of Laravel). And thanks everyone for the concern.